# How does writing to a database work when a web app uses multiple databases like Sitecore has

Tags: database, sitecore

In Sitecore you basically have three databases. The `Core`, `Master` and `Web` database.

Simply put the `Core` database holds all Sitecore settings. The `Master` database is the authoring database. So it contains all versions of any content.

Then in Sitecore you can "publish" the contents and it will publish the latest version of each content to the `Web` database.

So suppose I have a website with a news page. And a user is able to edit a news item from the web site (so not through the CMS). How would the database then get updated when it's set up like this?

It would probably update the `Web` database, but then when I go into the CMS I don't see the latest changes, since the CMS reads from the `Master` database, right?

So does that mean that it should write twice? Once to the `Web` database and once to the `Master` database?

Can anyone tell me how this works in Sitecore or the like?

---

The reason I'd like to know this is becasue I'm thinking of creating a similar database setup. And I'm just not sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have items that needs to be updated by the website visitor, you need to use the SitecoreService SOAP webservice or create your own custom webservice that runs on the Master-instance and triggers a publish after updating.

Comment: You can also use the [Item Web Api](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf) but you still have to call back to the CMS instance you as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Sitecore has a publishing step. When the user publishes in Sitecore, it updates the Web database at that point. If you want to build a similar system, I would simply store all versions of an item in the Master database and only when the user chooses to publish, copy the latest version to the Web database.

Answer (score 0):

If your site 
 - generates a lot of comments
 - generates the comments continuously
 - uses multiple content delivery servers
 - requires CMS users to manage them

I would not store the comments as content items.
The reason is HTML cache and publishing behavior.

On high volume site you'd most certainly use html caching to achieve best possible performance. If a publish is required to show comments, you'd need frequent publish actions and thus html caches are cleared often.
You don't wan't that :-)

Modeling after the DMS implementation is the safest (not cheapest and Datatables isn't something I recommend these days), storing stuff in a separate database, possibly using queuing to prevent an overload if things get busy..